# Pass variables inside a Function

Tags: php, class

I am trying to use the API for scheduling of my sessions. The variables $tutor_id, $tutorname, $date3, $topic etc have been set earlier

```
<?php   
class ScheduleClass
{
function ScheduleClass($secretAcessKey,$access_key,$webServiceUrl)
{

    require_once("AuthBase.php");
    $authBase = new AuthBase($secretAcessKey,$access_key);
    $method = "create";
    $requestParameters["signature"]=$authBase-
    >GenerateSignature($method,$requestParameters);
    $requestParameters["presenter_id"] =$tutor_id;
    $requestParameters["presenter_name"] = $tutorname ;  
    $requestParameters["start_time"] = $date3;
    $requestParameters["title"]=$topic; //Required
    $requestParameters["duration"]="10"; //optional
    $requestParameters["time_zone"]="Asia/Kolkata"; //optional
    $requestParameters["attendee_limit"]=""; //optional
    $requestParameters["control_category_id"]=""; //optional
    $requestParameters["create_recording"]=""; //optional
    $requestParameters["return_url"]= $return_url; //optional
    $requestParameters["status_ping_url"]=""; //optional
                $requestParameters["language_culture_name"]="en-us";

foreach($requestParameters as $x => $x_value) {
echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
echo "<br>";}
}//end function
}
require_once("keys.php");
$obj=new ScheduleClass($secretAcessKey,$access_key,$webServiceUrl);
?>
```

However the output comes like:

```
Key=access_key, Value=abcde
Key=timestamp, Value=1513613770
Key=method, Value=create
Key=signature, Value=abcde
Key=presenter_id, Value=
Key=presenter_name, Value=
Key=start_time, Value=
Key=title, Value=
Key=duration, Value=10
Key=time_zone, Value=Asia/Kolkata
Key=attendee_limit, Value=
Key=control_category_id, Value=
Key=create_recording, Value=
```

ie the variables set outside the class / Function are not being passed.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: You have a [Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. PHP classes and functions are not Lexically Scoped, so you'll have to pass those `$variable_agument`s into your class functions or use `global $varname`s.

Comment: Thanks PHPglue. You homed onto the exact issue.That did the trick.